# Abelian groups being isomorphic.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ and $H$ are groups. For an isomorphism $f:G\to H$ to exist, is it a condition that $G$ and $H$ are either both abelian, *or* that neither of them are abelian?

I recall seeing such a condition somewhere ... but I can't seem to find the proposition anywhere.

Comment: Anything that's determined entirely by the multiplication has to be preserved by isomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For them to be isomorphic they must both be abelian or both NOT being abelian, it's easy to see why, let $G$ be abelian, then we have that
$$ab=ba$$
for any elements, our isomorphism is $\varphi$, then we get that
$$\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)=\varphi(ba)=\varphi(b)\varphi(a)$$
so they must both be abelian then if one is.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, for an isomorphism $f\colon G\rightarrow H$ to exist, it is a **necessary** condition that either both $G$ and $H$ should be abelian or both should be non-abelian; but the condition is **not sufficient**.

In general, it is a difficult problem to decide whether two groups are isomorphic or not.